# iOS core data move save location

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to move my core data location so I can share it between the iPhone app and an Apple Watch app. Investigation so far shows that I need to use app containers for both apps to have access to the same core data information.

I've set the group up, and its added to both targets

```
group.Desbrina.dpl.Diamond-Painting-Logbook.shared
```

So, I've been following a tutorial at the below site,
https://medium.com/@manibatra23/sharing-data-using-core-data-ios-app-and-extension-fb0a176eaee9

and modified my app delegate, but the existing data isn't being loaded and new data isn't being saved. From what I can find I need to migrate the existing core data to the new location. I've not found anything yet that explains how to do it with the latest version of swift.

Currently the working version is loaded using

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Diamond_Painting_Logbook")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

The modified code for the new location I have as.

```
/*lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
 let container = NSCustomPersistentContainer(name: "Diamond_Painting_Logbook")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {

            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()*/

class NSCustomPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    override open class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        var storeURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.Desbrina.dpl.Diamond-Painting-Logbook.shared")
        storeURL = storeURL?.appendingPathComponent("Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite")
        return storeURL!
    }
}
```

I've tried using the below to move the store, but it errors on the mirgratePersisantStore line

```
persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Diamond_Painting_Logbook")
    persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Could not create CoreData store: \(error)")
        }
        var nURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.Desbrina.dpl.Diamond-Painting-Logbook.shared")
        nURL = nURL?.appendingPathComponent("Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite")
        if let newURL = nURL {
            do {
                let psc = self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator
                let store = psc.persistentStores[0]
                NSLog("7 *****************")
                try psc.migratePersistentStore(store, to: newURL, options: nil, withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
                NSLog("8 *****************")
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is

2019-11-23 19:55:45.132081+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] 7 *****************
2019-11-23 19:55:45.132863+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] [logging-persist] cannot open file at line 43353 of [378230ae7f]
2019-11-23 19:55:45.132901+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] [logging-persist] os_unix.c:43353: (0) open(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/BF375BFE-4AF0-4F78-BDEE-C4A4A12493B3/Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite) - Undefined error: 0
2019-11-23 19:55:45.132917+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] [logging] API call with unopened database connection pointer
2019-11-23 19:55:45.132929+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] [logging] misuse at line 162611 of [378230ae7f]
2019-11-23 19:55:45.133370+0000 Diamond Painting Logbook[6707:1813609] [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME URL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/BF375BFE-4AF0-4F78-BDEE-C4A4A12493B3/Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite/ options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption = 1;
} ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(256) with userInfo dictionary {
    NSFilePath = "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/BF375BFE-4AF0-4F78-BDEE-C4A4A12493B3/Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
}
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME URL:file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/BF375BFE-4AF0-4F78-BDEE-C4A4A12493B3/Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite/ options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption = 1;
} ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(256) with userInfo dictionary {
    NSFilePath = "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/BF375BFE-4AF0-4F78-BDEE-C4A4A12493B3/Diamond_Painting_Logbook.sqlite";
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
}